# Email from my Cloudflare server always go to spam folder of my recipient, how will I fix this?

Tags: email, cloudflare, bulk-email, google-analytics-spam

All my emails are sent to spam folder of my recipients. I already set up SPF, DKIM, and DMARC on my cloudflare, however, still it didn't make any difference. Is there any alternative way to resolved this? Or do I have to change another dns server? I just want to ensure all my emails are delivered to my recipient's inbox. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you google `email checking` you will find many sites that offer a service to check your email.  Try a few to see whats missing from your email.  The other thing is that your domain may have been marked as spam.  Again there are sites that will tell you this.

Comment: I don't think it's about your records. It's about the SMTP server. I looked into sending emails through CF too, but couldn't find the option right away. For now, I only receiving emails through CF, but not sending. What exactly is your SMTP and email set up?